# How can I edit a cell pressing an icon on my DataGrid WPF?

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms, datagrid, editing

I´ve tried to attach a event to the pencil icon and it works but only with the row that is selected in that moment even when is not the one where the pencil is pressed, I want that the event occurs only pressing the pencil icon and not depending which row is selected.
This is the creation of the column with the pencil icon and the event for a stackpanel

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="cinco" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding id4}" Foreground="#2ECBC6" FontSize="20" Margin="11,5" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                                <StackPanel PreviewMouseDown="StackPanel_PreviewMouseDown"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="LeadPencil" Foreground="#2ECBC6" Width="30" Height="30"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#2ECBC6"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This is the method that is called when the pencil icon is pressed

```
private void StackPanel_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        test test1 = new test();
        test1 = (test)ListNameTest.SelectedItem;
        if (test1 == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("seleccionar fila");
        }
        else
        {
            var dato = test1.id4;
            Content_OrdenTrabajo.Text = dato.ToString();
            Host_OrdenTrabajo.IsOpen = true;
            Keyboard_OrdenTrabajo.KeyboardState = Rife.Keyboard.KeyboardState.Numeric;
            test1.id4 = Content_OrdenTrabajo.Text;
        }
    }
```

[image: DataGrid example]

Comment: DataGrid is not a standard XF control.  If you are using some third party plugin, you need to tell us which one it is

Answer (score 0):

The `sender` parameter of the `StackPanel_PreviewMouseDown` method will contain the StackPanel on which the event was raised.
Since this StackPanel is a cell element, its DataContext will inherit from the cell.
And the DataContext of the cell is the collection item for which this row was created.

Example:

```
        private void StackPanel_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var stackPanel = (StackPanel)sender;
            var rowData = stackPanel.DataContext;
        }
```

To get property values, you need to add a rowData cast to the item type of the DataGrid.ItemsSource collection.

```
        test test1 = (test) ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
```